# Cannot send byte Data from Android App to Python Server using sockets

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, tcp

I have tried everything to get this to work. Basically I have an Android App which receives data from a Python based Server on a local network connection. I can receive Data no problem. However when I attempt to send data back the App crashes and the Python server receives blank data. I have tried several different approaches but non have worked. Here is the Python method I have written to receive the message:

```
   def checkReply(self):
    reply = "no reply yet"
    self.conn.settimeout(1)
    try:
        test =  self.conn.recv(1024)
    except:
        self.conn.timeout;
        print("I failed to hear this") #Debug to help see if I have heard an incomming message
    try:
        data = test.decode()

        reply = data
    except:
        print("I failed to decode this") #Debug to help see if I could not decode an incomming message
    print(reply)
    self.conn.settimeout(0)
```

My client on my Android application looks like this:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String response = "No data has been sent yet";
TextView textResponse;
Socket socket = null;


Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    this.textResponse = textResponse;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

     /*
      * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
      */
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            response = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("Ascii");
        }

        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    textResponse.setText(response);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

protected String getSite(){
    return response;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void returnMsg(){

        try (DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
            byte[] buf = "hello".getBytes("UTF-8");
            outToClient.writeBytes("Test");
            outToClient.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {}




}
```

}

I am having to test on a physical device so I have no log to trace the error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Stack trace/error message?

Comment: Sorry just edited the post there. I am testing on a physical device so I have no log to trace

Comment: ADB will get you the log trace.  http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-logcat

Comment: The device I am using to test cannot connect to Android Studio and the PC I am developing on cannot run virtual machines so I am stuck :/

Comment: Can you enable USB debugging on your device?  If so, do that and then run `adb logcat`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot :/

Comment: How are you even getting your code onto the device?

Comment: I have to build the app every time I wish to run it. It's an odd set up at University and I cannot run it on my own laptop

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly.  Do you have any communication with the device?  USB/network?  There are also Google Play apps available that will show you the logcat.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have no communication between android studio and the device. I will look into the play store alternative :)

Comment: I'm genuinely curious - how do you actually transfer your code from Android Studio to the device? :)

Comment: I have to build the APK and then use some means to transfer the APK to my device and then install in on the device. It's time consuming but my only option currently :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. I needed to flush the buffer before trying to send any data back via the socket